# Connect OV7670 camera to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, camera

I've recently bought an Arducam OV7670. The man who sold it to me told me that it was compatible with Raspberry Pi (naïve me to believe him). I've been googling but I've found nothing crystal clear. This forum speaks about the subject: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=73190

Someone says that it is possible to connect it but using some kind of board interface:

> Even with a FIFO board, the problem is that the Pi I/O's are not organized for a byte wide high speed interface, so I don't think they could handle the 25MB/sec data rate (I could be wrong, if the GPIO's can be reconfigured to provide a byte wide port that does not require reshuffling the bits)

This confused me a little bit, because there is a port for Raspberry Pi of the Arducam library: 
https://github.com/ArduCAM/RaspberryPi/tree/master/ArduCAM4Pi.

Besides, the datasheet of the camera says it is compatible with ARM architectures (http://www.arducam.com/camera-modules/0-3mp-ov7670/):

> Can be used in Arduino, Maple, ChipKit, STM32, ARM, DSP, FPGA
>   platforms

Any thoughts? Is there a connection schema out there so I can follow it?

Comment: in this context "ARM" = "ARM Cortex-M microcontrollers", which the Raspberry Pi doesn't have

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bare OV7670modules don't seem to be compatible, but the [ArduCAM Mini](http://www.arducam.com/arducam-mini-released/) incorporates a controller and SPI output. This is what the code on github appears to be for, along with this [installation guide](http://www.arducam.com/downloads/shields/simple_guide_V2.pdf).